# Oracle Query - Selecting records using column data from first table

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle, I have tables that I need to query.  There is one main table which has a field containing the name of all the other tables. (one per row)

First table (table1) has a column that has the table name of second table (table1.table2name).

Second tables have a date field (datetocheck).  I want to bring back only records from the first table if there are no records newer than 6 months in the second table (table2 has the date, table1 has the data I want to display).

It would be something in this format:

```
select * from table1 
where not exists (
                  select * from table1.table2name
                  where datetocheck > add_months(sysdate, -6)
                 )
```

Thanks Before Hand

**Additional Info**

There is ONE table1 and MANY table2's.

For example

## Main Table (table1)

record 1: column:table2name='Table2a'

record 2: column:table2name='Table2b'

record 3: column:table2name='Table2c'

## Additional Tables (table2x)

---Table2a

record 1: column:datetocheck='01/01/1980'

record 2: column:datetocheck='01/01/1990'

record 3: column:datetocheck='01/01/2000'

---Table2b

record 1: column:datetocheck='01/01/1982'

record 2: column:datetocheck='01/01/1983'..etc

---Table2c

record 1: column:datetocheck='01/01/2014'

record 2: column:datetocheck='02/01/2014'..etc

**Note #1**: The only relationship between table1 and table2x are the table2name column in table1 and the actual table name in the table2x's.

Comment: OK, so what have you tried?

Comment: You can't dynamically refer to a table name in a SQL statement.  You need something like a prepared statement or a cursor.

Comment: Look here: http://thinkoracle.blogspot.it/2005/09/column-name-as-variable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DBMS_XMLGEN` to make dynamic sqls inside a query:

```
select *
from table1 as t1
where dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select * from ' || 
                             t1.table2name ||
                             ' where datetocheck > add_months(sysdate, -6)
').extract('//text()').getstringval() is not null
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cfa778/7)

Comment: A.B. Cade, thank you, you are definitely on the right track.  One quick question, how would I pull the table2name if its in one of the fields of table1?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question, I editted my answer to have an alias to table1 as `t1` so you can see that I pulled the value with `t1.table2name`

Comment: Tried your example and it works perfect.  Wow, congrats and thanks.  Marked as answer.

Comment: A.B. Cade, do you know if there is an easy way to check if table2x exists?  I am getting an error because some tables are in a table1 row but the table (table2x) does not exist.

Comment: Had an idea - to join `table1` with `user_tables` so only existing tables will be queried, but unfortunately you can't be sure what part of the where clause will be evaluted first... anyway, found a way to do this (i think) but it's ugly. See here in the [new demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8479/17)