# Dynamically selecting table name using sub-query in from clause

Tags: oracle, dynamic

I have a mapping table with source and table name as attributes.

And i have the below query :

```
select *
from 
(select table_name from mapping_table where source='CL Table')
```

I want to retrieve the data of the `table_name` but this query will return only the table name not the data.

How to do it?

Comment: You have to make it Dynamic. So many ways are possible! But problem is using the column names in it.. As you may not know what column is in it. IF you know the Column name before hand it is very simple!

Comment: What client you use? For Example: `JAVA`(_JDBC_)/`PHP`(_ADO_) ?

Comment: Maybe this question can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555997/oracle-query-selecting-records-using-column-data-from-first-table/21556595#21556595

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE
    v_mystring VARCHAR(50);
    v_my_ref_cursor sys_refcursor;
    myrecord <some_table_or_type>;
  BEGIN

    select table_name into my_table_name
      from mapping_table 
    where source='CL Table';

    v_mystring := 'SELECT * from '||my_table_name;;

    OPEN v_my_ref_cursor FOR v_mystring;

    LOOP
      FETCH v_my_ref_cursor INTO myrecord;
      -- your processing
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE v_my_ref_cursor;
  END;
```

Comment: So, now I have to call a proc in the from clause ? Can I return the entire query result set from proc to the from clause ? Is it possible ?